# PyPDF2 : not able to add/merge watermark in all pages in pdf

Tags: python, watermark, pypdf

I just want to add a watermark/background on all the pages depending upon the orientation of each page. The watermark/background will be different for the portrait and landscape-oriented pages.

Here is my code just to add watermark in all pages

```
from typing import BinaryIO
import PyPDF4
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter, PdfFileMerger
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from fpdf import FPDF

input_file = askopenfilename()
pdf = PdfFileReader(input_file)
watermark = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('F:\abc\abc\PDF 
Templates\Report First - Potrait.pdf', 'rb'))
output = PdfFileWriter()

watermarks = watermark.getPage(0)

with open(input_file, "rb+") as filehandle_input:
# read content of the original file
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(filehandle_input)
print(pdfReader.numPages)
total_numbers = pdfReader.getNumPages()
for i in range(0,total_numbers):
    if i < total_numbers:
        deg = pdf.getPage(i).get('/Rotate')
        page = pdf.getPage(i).mediaBox
        if page.getUpperRight_x() - page.getUpperLeft_x() > page.getUpperRight_y() - page.getLowerRight_y():
            if deg in [0, 180, None]:
                print('Landscape1')
            else:
                print('Portrait1')

        else:
            if deg in [0, 180, None]:
                print('Portrait2')
                page_s = pdfReader.getPage(i)
                page_s.mergePage(watermarks)
                output.addPage(page_s)

            else:
                print('Landscape2')

with open(input_file.rsplit(".", 1)[0] + '_FP.pdf', "wb") as merged_file:
    output.write(merged_file)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\PFD python\abc\PFD python\test2.py", line 23, in <module>
    page.mergePage(watermarks)
  File "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 2417, in mergePage
    self._mergePage(page2)
  File "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 2426, in _mergePage
    originalResources = self[PG.RESOURCES].getObject()
  File "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 539, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key).getObject()
KeyError: '/Resources'
```

Comment: Actually, the input file contains the mixed type of pages ( landscape & portrait) and watermark is nothing but a header ( company logo with some text) so different kinds of watermarks.. Counting total number of pages & Identify the page rotation is possible with above code but as soon as start adding the page_s = pdfReader.getPage(i)  page_s.mergePage(watermarks)     The code start giving me error as it does not recognize mergePage with for loop. Sorry its been only 3 days I stated learning python and I don't have any coding background. Treat me as a NOOB.

Comment: Everything is already updated and I have done all kinds of research and was only able to find this "Python3 support for ASCII85Decode" but I really don't understand how to do it?

Comment: Thanks K J for helping me out . Well now my problem get resolved. I don't what, but there was something wrong with my input file only and I was totally stupid not try another input file in past 3 days. So I learnt a new lesson if there is any error, try to change every possible thing .. And now I am able to use different kind of watermark for landscape and portrait pages..